# What's wrong with my code, why it is not implementing colour on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is  my JavaScript code:

```js
function setColor(){

   var x=document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx = x.getContext('2d');
   var pixel = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
   //var data = pixel.data;

   //var clrss = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
   for (var i = 0; i < pixel.data.length; i+=4) {

          //red
          pixel.data[i] = 230;
          // green
          pixel.data[i + 1] = 170;
          // blue
          pixel.data[i + 2] = 255;
          //alpha
          //data[i + 3] = 0;
console.log("blue");
        }

        // overwrite original image
        ctx.putImageData(pixel, 0, 0);
      }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br>
<img id="PM" src="PM.png">
<input type="button" onclick="setColor();" value="BTest">
```

Comment: You haven't set the image.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the size of the canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas><br>
<img id="PM" src="PM.png">
<input type="button" onclick="setColor();" value="BTest">
```

Comment: It do not added the colour on background image, It changes whole canvas's colour, Is there any simple solution except this one for adding the colour on Image?